# React and Mobx - Load API data on load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have to validate that the user is logged in, using some token, that currently in the next example will already be set, for testing.

I have two options that I can think of.

**Option 1**

Do it on store's constructor:

```
export class MyStore {

    @observable token = "sometoken";
    @observable authenticated = false;

    constructor() {
        this.checkAuth();
    }

    @action
    checkAuth() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/validate/" + this.token)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.authenticated = data.validated;
            });
            // catch etc
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Do it in my component's that uses the data, `componentDidMount` method.

Both of the ways work, but what is really the best practice to handle such state?

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/mobx-react-best-practices-17e01cec4140

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for the first option. If you don't always need the authentication - for example some parts are public - then just don't call `this.checkAuth()` in the store constructor. If all parts need authentication, then it looks good like this.
Option 2 should be avoided because that would make unnecessary roundtrips to the server to re-validate a token which was already validated. And in general MobX gives great tools to minimize the use of lifecycle methods and write a cleaner code.